# How to rotate picture on google map in android ,

Tags: android, google-maps, overlay, drawimage

I have many Ovarlay Item , I could draw them all, My question is how i rotate the image to south north ease west , please help me

Answer (score -1):

If you only need it to be at 0,90,180 and 270 degrees then just create four images each rotated to the proper angle in paint or whatever and choose the one you want.